# How to load PCM data into AudioKit?

Tags: pcm, audiokit

I'm new to AudioKit. I've been through the examples, which are very instructional and straightforward. What I want to do is connect an existing iOS application where I have PCM data available and pass that into AudioKit so I can add effects. I thought I'd be able to use an AKNode for this, but I don't see how to load a simple array.

I also took a look at AKMicrophone and AKStereoInput thinking I could overwrite them, but they seem to use AVAudioNode's.

I think I'm missing something simple here? How do I load my PCM data into AudioKit? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is a node needs to be able to supply a constant stream of data as its being requested by downstream nodes.  So you need to create a generator node. Instead of looking at microphone, which grabs that data from hardware.  I'd start by look at AKOscillatorDSP.mm and modify it:

```
void YourDSP::process(AUAudioFrameCount frameCount, AUAudioFrameCount bufferOffset) {

    for (int frameIndex = 0; frameIndex < frameCount; ++frameIndex) {
        int frameOffset = int(frameIndex + bufferOffset);

        float temp = 0;
        for (int channel = 0; channel < _nChannels; ++channel) {
            float *out = (float *)_outBufferListPtr->mBuffers[channel].mData + frameOffset;

            *out = ... whatever your magic is ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's very helpful, @Aurelius! Thank you! Modifying this code looks like it would work. But I'm also realizing that probably a more proper integration would be to use AudioUnits and create a whole new node. My app already uses AudioUnits. I'm a novice here but I would think I could follow AKOscillator and AKOscillatorAudioUnit to create new classes? Then my audio buffer lists would just pass normally?

Comment: So... I'm totally overthinking this. Since my app uses an AudioUnit for output, this is trivial and just works. I did a quick test project and everything is awesome. (I don't completely understand it all, but I'll get there.)

Comment: Aurelius, I implemented what you suggested except that I started by creating a new subclasss of AKDSPBase. It works well! After I clean up and test further in my app, I'll check if it might make a good addition to AudioKit. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Definitely would love to have this as a contribution to AudioKit, make a pull request!